# Unity3d : Creating GUIText On Runtime

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying to create a Text that describes an object on Runtime, the GUIText object is created but it is not visible. any ideas ?

here is my code :

```
void enemydescriptionInit( GameObject text, string desc){
    text.transform.parent = enemyCar1.car.transform;
    enemyCar1.car.transform.position = enemyCar1.startPosiotion;
    text.gameObject.GetComponent<GUIText> ().font = new Font ("Arial");
    text.gameObject.GetComponent<GUIText>().text = desc;
    text.gameObject.GetComponent<GUIText>().fontSize = 40;
    text.gameObject.GetComponent<GUIText>().fontStyle = FontStyle.BoldAndItalic;
    text.gameObject.GetComponent<GUIText>().color = Color.blue;
    text.gameObject.name = "Desc";

}

void Start () {
    player = GameObject.Find ("Player");

    text = new GameObject();
    text.AddComponent<GUIText>();
  }


void Update(){
enemydescriptionInit (text, "HELLO");
}
```

Comment: GUIText is a Legacy-Component. Try using the [new UI](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/UIOverview.html) (since Version 4.6). It is much easier to handle.

Comment: i agree with Marius Junak - use Unity 5 - it has all the Pro features for free and the new UI is much, much better.

Comment: this is my first project with unity and i am using Unity 5, what do you guys mean by using "new UI" ?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Unity 5 try using `UnityEngine.UI`

And instead of `GUIText`just use `Text`

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

Try on OnGUI() method

this example code

```
void OnGUI(){

            GUIStyle style = new GUIStyle();
            style.fontSize = 30;
            style.alignment = TextAnchor.UpperRight;
            GUI.Label (new Rect(Screen.width/2 , 10 , 100 ,40) , "Time left " + secondsLeft.ToString() , style);


    }
```